# How to count gini in dataset using excel?

Tags: excel, counting, gini

Im try to manually count gini for my 300 datasets with two columns with 5 index using excel. But im still dont know how to count in exce. it's so confusing.

data1:
[image]
[data2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56mkR.jpg)
[data3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHpYV.jpg)

from my data next columns is 0,1,2,3,4 each every index have 30 data. i want to get gini from my decision tree with test size= 50
[decisiontree from dataset with testsize 50](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwjoq.png)

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Use `COUNTIFS()` function. Post few sample data and show desired output.

Comment: can you give examples how to do it ?

Comment: What will be your expected result? What will be criteria to count?

Comment: gini result from my decision tree with 50 test size